# Color-coded 3rd and 4th columns in Python scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a simple scatter plot with color-coded points based on two columns. What I have is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = ("master.kkids.obslist")

data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=14,dtype=str)

x = data[:,7]
y = data[:,8]
u = data[:,18]
v = data[:,19]
z = data[:,20]

x1 = x.astype(float)
y1 = y.astype(float)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.savefig('hi.png')
```

Now, I'm new to Python, and my Googling hasn't answered this question:

How can I make the colors of the points respond to the U, V, and Z columns? Say, for instance, column U has either "Y" or "N" in it. How can I make "N" points come up grey, and "Y" points come up red? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an argument containing array of colors to the `scatter` function, like this:

```
colors = ["grey" if s == "N" else "red" for s in u]
plt.scatter(x1, y2, c=colors)
```

This code fills the list `colors` with strings "grey" and "red" depending whether on which elements in `u` are "Y" and which "N", and then passes it to the `scatter` function.

If you need more complex logic when choosing the right color, I suggest to move it to a separate function. Let's name it `c()` and pass the elements of U, V, and Z as arguments to it.

```
def c(u1, v1, z1):
    if u1 == "N": return "grey"
    ... # other logic...

colors = [c(u1, v1, z1) for (u1, v1, z1) in zip(u, v, z)]
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Second question for you: would it be possible to make a different column change the shape of the point, rather than the color? Or in addition to the color?

Comment: @uhurulol I don't think so. But you can call `scatter` multiple times, passing different `marker` arguments and each time incude only the points you want to draw with that specific marker shape.